How to typeset arithmetic exercise on completing schemes of operations?


How can typeset these elementary operations algorithm schemes?

welcome! what have you tried? questions which just post an image and ask for code are not really reasonable ones for this site. generally, questions should ask how to solve a particular problem.

As a starting point / hint, you should be able to create these using the tabular environment. The partial horizontal line can be created with \cmidrule.
If you can figure it out from there, you may as well post your own answer to this question.
If not, alter the question, adding with what you were able to figure out, and where you got stuck.

Maybe you should try the xlop package.

It shouldn't be hard to copy what's been done with a typewriter and, perhaps, improve on it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{k}{w{c}{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{opscheme}[2][t]
 {$% enter math mode 
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}% wider space between rows
  \mathcode`?=\mathcode`* % avoid problems with *
  \begin{array}[#1]{#2}% start the array
 }
 {\end{array}$}

\begin{document}

(a)\qquad 
   \begin{opscheme}{@{} *{4}{k} | *{3}{k} @{}}
   ? & ? & 8 & ? && ? & ? \\
   \cline{5-7}
     & ? & 9 & 1 && 3 & 2 \\
     &   & 4 & ?
   \end{opscheme}

\bigskip

(a)\qquad
   \begin{opscheme}{@{} *{5}{k} @{}}
     & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
     &   &   & ? & ? \\
   \midrule
   ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
   ? & ? & ? & ? &  \\
   \midrule
   9 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 9
   \end{opscheme}

\end{document}

Why the question marks instead of the asterisks? Because asterisks in array may lead to unexpected problems. Besides, this allows to change the symbol for an unknown entry to anything you like (including a question mark, of course).

You can change the vertical positioning with \begin{opscheme}[c] or \begin{opscheme}[b] (try your hand at them).
